# Decrease Prometheus scraping interval on k8s for one Pod

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Our global Prometheus scrape interval on k8s is `60s`, but I want one application has `300s` scrape interval.

I attach the following to my pod so the metrics are **scraped**.

```
prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
prometheus.io/port: '{{ .Values.prometheus.port }}'
prometheus.io/path: '{{ .Values.prometheus.path }}'
```

Now I want to slow down the frequency of this application specifically, and tested with

```
prometheus.io/interval: '300s'
```

However it does not work. I think it requires `relabel`, or any other suggestion?
https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml#L251

Comment: FYI it’s scraped not scrapped

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add some details. If you use the official Prometheus Helm charts, this should be in your `values-prometheus.yaml` file:

```
# extra scraping configs
# | is required, because extraScrapeConfigs is expected to be a string
extraScrapeConfigs: |
  - job_name: 'kubernetes-service-endpoints-scrape-every-2s'

    scrape_interval: 2s

    kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints

    relabel_configs:
      #Custom
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_example_com_scrape_every_2s]
        action: keep
        regex: true

      # Boilerplate
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme]
        action: replace
        target_label: __scheme__
        regex: (https?)
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
        action: replace
        target_label: __metrics_path__
        regex: (.+)
      - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
        action: replace
        target_label: __address__
        regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
        replacement: $1:$2
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
        action: replace
        target_label: kubernetes_namespace
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
        action: replace
        target_label: kubernetes_name
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name]
        action: replace
        target_label: kubernetes_node
```

To upgrade the existing(default) installation:

```
helm upgrade prometheus --values values-prometheus.yaml stable/prometheus
```

On the service or the pod you can now add these annotations:

```
prometheus.io/path: /metrics
prometheus.io/port: "9090"
example.com/scrape_every_2s: "true"
```

Remove the original `prometheus.io/scrape: "true"`, because otherwise your service will show up as two separate Prometheus targets, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: As a side note, you can now add `prometheus.io/scrape-slow: "true"` to only scrape every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

In Prometheus you can set `scrape_interval` both **globally** and more specifically **per job**. Value defined per job overrides the global one. Compare with [this](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/release-2.12/config/testdata/conf.good.yml) example.

For more details please refer to official Prometheus [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/).

---

EDIT:

Below an example of a job with `scrape_interval` set to `300s`. It selects for scraping only `Pods` that have `example.io/should_be_scraped_every_300s: "true"` annotation:

```
  - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods-300s'

    scrape_interval: 300s

    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: pod

    # example relabel to scrape only pods that have 'example.io/should_be_scraped_every_300s: "true"' annotation
    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_example_io_should_be_scraped_every_300s]
      action: keep
      regex: true

    # rest of this config was taken from default 'kubernetes-pods' job already present in default Prometheus config
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
      action: keep
      regex: true
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
      action: replace
      target_label: __metrics_path__
      regex: (.+)
    - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
      action: replace
      regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
      replacement: $1:$2
      target_label: __address__
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
      action: replace
      target_label: kubernetes_namespace
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
      action: replace
      target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
```

And below fragment of `Pod` definition that contains appropriate annotations so that it will be discovered by Prometheus as a target to be scraped.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod 
metadata:
  annotations:
    example.io/should_be_scraped_every_300s: "true"
    kubernetes.io/limit-ranger: 'LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container
      buildroot'
    prometheus.io/path: /metrics
    prometheus.io/port: "9090"
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
...
```

Comment: It does not work using k8s pod annotation `prometheus.io/scrape_interval: '300s'`. using k8s the metrics are scrapped by a special pod that collects all the metrics of pods that exported to an endpoint, e.g. `/metrics`

Comment: Because it doesn't work this way. You cannot define `scrape_interval` via `annotations` in `Pod` definition. It works on different level and no relabelling will help you here. As I already mentioned above, `scrape_interval` can be defined both globally and per specific job in Prometheus config passed via `ConfigMap`. If you need to scrape specific `Pod` or set of `Pods` not as often as any other `Pods`, you need to define a new job in Prometheus config and select such `Pods` by appropriate label and its value in `relabel_configs` section.

Comment: I edited my answer by adding an example of such `job` to make it clearer.